# GWT Hyperlink not working

Tags: gwt, hyperlink, widget

I'm getting a problem with a gwt hyperlink, in fact it is not working, Ok, when I'm placing my cursor on the hyperlink, I cannot press on the hyperlink, it is as if a label!! :

**GWT Codes:**

```
Hyperlink hprlnkArt = new Hyperlink("Art", false, "Interest=14");
grid.setWidget(0, 6, hprlnkArt);
grid.getCellFormatter().setStyleName(0, 6, "interestBarGridSlot");
hprlnkArt.setStyleName("interestBarIcons");
```

**Corresponding CSS Styles:**

```
.interestBarIcons 
{
   width:106px;
    text-align:center;
}

.interestBarGridSlot 
{
    background:black;

}

.interestBarGridSlot a
{
    color:white !important;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:17px;   
}

.InterestTitle
{
    font-size:20px;
    font-Weight:bold;   
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean by "not working".

Comment: Ok, when I'm placing my cursor on the hyperlink, I cannot press on the hyperlink, it is as if a label!!

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `Hyperlink` is a slightly misleading class name in GWT. It is not actually rendered as an `<a>` tag, it is rendered as a `<div>` and is for `internal` history system based navigation within the app. That's why your CSS styles are probably not working on it either.

If you want a real "hyperlink" you need to use the `Anchor` widget.

Comment: `Hyperlink` *is* rendered as an `<a>`. Within a `<div>` yes, but it's still an `<a>` (have a look at `InlineHyperlink` for the version without the wrapper `<div>`). `Hyperlink` always uses `href="#xxx"` kind of links, so it always links _inside_ the app, but that doesn't mean it's not a _real "hyperlink"_ (I admit the name can be misleading re. `Anchor`, but that's legacy you have to live with in many projects if you don't want to break backwards compatibility)